# Google Calendar and Google spreadsheet Sync: performance issue

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

Well well. I made a script that:

1. Download all (30 years) calendar Events in a spreadsheet (sheet0) with function (Sincronizza) and if empty, create an History (sheet1)
2. Check if Current Events in my calendar are the same of History and if not do things:
   2.1. if expired postpone event to tomorrow
   2.2. if obsoleted (there is an update on a field) it updates History
   2.3. if new it interts in History
3. Check if some events that are in History but are not in current calendar and delete them with Pulisci fucntion.

I met these problems:

1. runtime longer than 6 min -> i had to create triggers
2. triggers >20 -> i had to delete triggers.

NOW it is working BUT to match 700 rows in sheet0 vs 700 rows in sheet1 it takes like 16 Hours.
Is there a way to make it faster?

best regards

Andrea

---

```
function CancellaTrigger(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  Logger.log('Current project has ' + ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length + ' triggers.')
  for (var i_trig = 0; i_trig < (triggers.length); i_trig++) {
  if(triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId() !== '16973849')
    {
    Logger.log("Cancello: " + (i_trig) + " trigger: " + triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId())
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i_trig])}
  Logger.log("Rimane il trigger solito Trigger: " + triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId())
  }
  
}

function TrovaTrigger(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  Logger.log('Current project has ' + ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length + ' triggers.')
  for (var i_trig = 0; i_trig < (triggers.length); i_trig++) {
  if(triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId() !== '')
    {
    Logger.log("Cancellerei :" + (i_trig) + " trigger: " + triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId())
  }
  Logger.log(triggers[i_trig].getUniqueId())
  }
}

/* REFERENCES
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event?hl=it
*/

// When open refresh menu
/*function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {
      name: "Sincronizza Immobile",
      functionName: "Sincronizza"
    }
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Sincronizza', menuEntries);
}
*/

function Sincronizza() {

  Logger.log("Sincronizza: START")
  // Calendar ID can be found in the "Calendar Address" section of the Calendar Settings.
  var calendarId ='XXXX@gmail.com';

  //Configure the year range you want to synchronize, e.g.: [2006, 2017].
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + '/' + mm  + '/' + yyyy;

  var years = [yyyy, yyyy+10];

  //Get calendar and events

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(new Date('01/01/' + (years && years.length ? years[0] : '1970')), new Date('12/31/' + (years && years.length ? years[years.length - 1] : '2050')));

  // Get spreadsheet and data

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar')
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Storico')
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('LOG')
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  var maxrighesheet0 = sheet0.getLastRow()
  sheet0.getRange('2:' + Math.max(maxrighesheet0,2)).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})
  Logger.log("Sincronizza: Riempio spreadsheet")
  // Fill spreadsheet
  for (var i = 0; i < calEvents.length; i++) {
  var calEvent = calEvents[i];
  sheet0.getRange('A'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getId())
  sheet0.getRange('B'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getTitle())
  sheet0.getRange('C'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getStartTime())
  sheet0.getRange('D'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getEndTime())
  sheet0.getRange('E'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getDescription())
  sheet0.getRange('F'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getDateCreated())
  sheet0.getRange('G'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getColor())
  sheet0.getRange('H'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getLastUpdated())
  sheet0.getRange('I'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getLocation())
  sheet0.getRange('J'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getCreators())
  sheet0.getRange('K'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getOriginalCalendarId())
  sheet0.getRange('L'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getPopupReminders())
  sheet0.getRange('M'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.isAllDayEvent())
  sheet0.getRange('N'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.isRecurringEvent())
  sheet0.getRange('O'+ (i+2)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))  
  }

  Logger.log ("Lo storico è vuoto? "+ (sheet1.getRange('A2').getValue()===''))
  if (sheet1.getRange('A2').getValue()=== '') {
    for (var i = 0; i < calEvents.length; i++) {
      var calEvent = calEvents[i];
      sheet1.getRange('A'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getId())
      sheet1.getRange('B'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getTitle())
      sheet1.getRange('C'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getStartTime())
      sheet1.getRange('D'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getEndTime())
      sheet1.getRange('E'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getDescription())
      sheet1.getRange('F'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getDateCreated())
      sheet1.getRange('G'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getColor())
      sheet1.getRange('H'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getLastUpdated())
      sheet1.getRange('I'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getLocation())
      sheet1.getRange('J'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getCreators())
      sheet1.getRange('K'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getOriginalCalendarId())
      sheet1.getRange('L'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.getPopupReminders())
      sheet1.getRange('M'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.isAllDayEvent())
      sheet1.getRange('N'+ (i+2)).setValue(calEvent.isRecurringEvent())
      sheet1.getRange('O'+ (i+2)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
    };
  }

  var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", 2)
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", 2)
  Logger.log("Sono " + i + " eventi nel calendario")
  Logger.log("Sincronizza: END. Calendarizzato confronta")
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("confronta")
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(currTime + (1000 * 5))) //5 secondi
    .create();
}

function confronta(){

  
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  CancellaTrigger()
  Logger.log("Confronta: START")

  // Calendar ID can be found in the "Calendar Address" section of the Calendar Settings.
  var calendarId ='XXXX@gmail.com';

// Configure the year range you want to synchronize, e.g.: [2006, 2017]
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
 var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 today = dd + '/' + mm  + '/' + yyyy;

 var years = [yyyy, yyyy+10];

 // Get calendar and events
 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(new Date('01/01/' + (years && years.length ? years[0] : '1970')), new Date('12/31/' + (years && years.length ? years[years.length - 1] : '2050')));

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var startI= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_I');
  var startJ= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_J');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar');
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Storico');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('LOG');

  var maxrighesheet0 = sheet0.getLastRow();
  var maxrighesheet1 = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var maxrighesheet2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
  
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + '/' + mm  + '/' + yyyy;

  var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  var dd = String(tomorrow.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(tomorrow.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = tomorrow.getFullYear();
  tomorrow = dd + '/' + mm  + '/' + yyyy;

  var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();

 /* Logger.log("Delta Time: " + (currTime - startTime))
  Logger.log("startI: " + startI)
  Logger.log("startJ: " + startJ)
  Logger.log("CurrTime: " + currTime)
  Logger.log("StartTime: " + startTime)
  Logger.log("maxrighesheet0: " + maxrighesheet0)*/
  
  Logger.log("confronto tra Downloaded from Calendar e Storico")
  for (var i = Math.max(startI,2); i <= maxrighesheet0; i++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(currTime - startTime >=  1000 * 60 * 5) { //5 minuti
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", i)
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", Math.max(startJ,2));
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("confronta")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime + (1000 * 5))) //5 secondi
               .create();
      Logger.log("Confronta: Sono uscito loop I a i: " + i +"/"+maxrighesheet0 +" e j: " +j + "/"+maxrighesheet1)
      break;
    } else {
      for (var j = Math.max(startJ,2); j <= maxrighesheet1; j++) {
        var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        if(currTime - startTime >=  1000 * 60 * 5) { //5 minuti
          i=i-1;
          scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", j);
          Logger.log("Confronta: Sono uscito loop J a i: " + i +"/"+maxrighesheet0 +" e j: " +j + "/"+maxrighesheet1)
          break;
          }   else {
      
        //Logger.log("I: " + i + " e J: " + j) 
        //Logger.log("Delta Time: " + (currTime - startTime))
        Logger.log("startI: " + startI)
        Logger.log("startJ: " + startJ)
        /*Logger.log("CurrTime: " + currTime)
        Logger.log("StartTime: " + startTime)
        Logger.log("TEST? " + (currTime - startTime >=  1000 * 60 * 5))*/


        Logger.log (i + "/" + maxrighesheet0 + " i/maxrighesheet0")
        Logger.log (j + "/" + maxrighesheet1 + " j/maxrighesheet1")
        Logger.log("Titolo sheet0: " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())
        Logger.log("Titolo sheet1: " + sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue())
        //Logger.log("Riccorrente?: " + sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue())
        Logger.log("Data Scadenza? S0: " + sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue())
        Logger.log("Data Scadenza? S1: " + sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue())
        //Logger.log("Last Upd? S0: " + sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue())
        //Logger.log("Last Upd? S1: " + sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue())
        
        /*Logger.log ("TEST:" )
        Logger.log(sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue())
        Logger.log(sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()!==sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf())
        Logger.log(sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf())
        Logger.log(sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())*/

        //1. task presente nello storico ma scaduto
        if (
        sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
        sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()!==true &&                                                                            //0 RICORRENTE?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()<new Date().valueOf())                                      //1 E' SCADUTO?
          {sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
          sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[EXP] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
          sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
          maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
          sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j))
          sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).setValue(today)
          sheet0.getRange('D'+ (i)).setValue(tomorrow)
          calEvents[i-2].setAllDayDate(new Date(sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).getValue()))
          sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).setValue(tomorrow)
          j=maxrighesheet1
          Logger.log("1. Task presente nello storico ma scaduto -> Insierisco Storico, Log, Aggiorno data e Push nel Calendario i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}
      
        //2. task presente nello storico e da aggiornare ma non scaduto 
        else if (
        sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
        sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()!==true &&                                                                            //0 RICORRENTE?
        sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf()!==sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf() &&          //0 LAST UPDATE E' LO STESSO
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())                                     //0 E' SCADUTO?
          {sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
          sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[OBS] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
          sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
          maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
          sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j))
          j=maxrighesheet1
          Logger.log ("2. task presente nello storico ma non scaduto e da aggiornare -> Insierisco Storico, Log i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}

        //3. task presente nello storico aggiornato ma scaduto (ricorrente)
        else if(      
        sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
        sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()===true &&                                                                            //1 RICORRENTE?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf() &&                                          //1 RICORRENTE E DATA CREATA LA STESSA?
        sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf() &&          //1 LAST UPDATE E' LO STESSO
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()<new Date().valueOf())                                      //1 E' SCADUTO?
          {sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
          sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[EXP] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
          sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
          maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
          sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j))
          sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).setValue(today)
          sheet0.getRange('D'+ (i)).setValue(tomorrow)
          calEvents[i-2].setAllDayDate(new Date(sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).getValue()))
          sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j)).setValue(tomorrow)
          j=maxrighesheet1
          Logger.log("3. task presente nello storico aggiornato ma scaduto (ricorrente) -> Insierisco Storico, Log, Aggiorno data e Push nel Calendario i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}

        //4. task presente nello storico da aggiornare ma non scaduto (ricorrente)
        else if(
        sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
        sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()===true &&                                                                            //1 RICORRENTE?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf() &&                                          //1 RICORRENTE E DATA CREATA LA STESSA?
        sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf()!==sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf()&&               //0 LAST UPDATE E' LO STESSO?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())                                     //0 E' SCADUTO?
          {sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
          sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[OBS] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
          sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
          maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
          sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j))
      j=maxrighesheet1
      Logger.log ("4. task presente nello storico da aggiornare ma non scaduto (ricorrente) -> Insierisco Storico, Log i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}

        //5. task presente nello storico
        else if(
        sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
        sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()===true &&                                                                            //1 RICORRENTE?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf() &&                                          //1 RICORRENTE E DATA CREATA LA STESSA?
        sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf()===sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf()&&               //1 LAST UPDATE E' LO STESSO?
        sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())                                     //0 E' SCADUTO?
          {j=maxrighesheet1
      //Logger.log ("5. task presente nello storico non da aggiornare  non scaduto (ricorrente) -> Non faccio nulla i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())
      }

      //6. 7. task (presente o no) nello storico non scaduto/scaduto (ricorrente) ma non trova la data
        else if(
          sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()===true &&                                                                          //1 RICORRENTE?)
          j===maxrighesheet1){ //e grazie al cazzo
            if(
              sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())   
              {sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange((maxrighesheet1+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet1+1)))
              maxrighesheet1 = maxrighesheet1 + 1
              j=maxrighesheet1
              Logger.log ("6. task (presente o no) nello storico (ricorrente) non scaduto ma non trova la data -> Inserisco Storico i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}
            else if (
            sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()<new Date().valueOf())                                      //0 E' SCADUTO?
              {sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange((maxrighesheet1+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet1+1)))
              maxrighesheet1 = maxrighesheet1 + 1
              sheet1.getRange((j+1)+':'+(j+1)).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
              sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[EXP] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
              sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
              maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
              sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).setValue(today)
              sheet0.getRange('D'+ (i)).setValue(tomorrow)
              calEvents[i-2].setAllDayDate(new Date(sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).getValue()))
              sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).setValue(tomorrow)
              j=maxrighesheet1
              Logger.log ("7. task (presente o no) nello storico (ricorrente) ma non trova la data ed è scaduto -> Insierisco Storico, Log, Aggiorno data e Push nel Calendario i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}
            }

          //8. e 9. Nuovo task non presente nello storico ma non scaduto/scaduto
        else if(
          sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue()===sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() &&
          sheet0.getRange('N' +i).getValue()===false)
          {j=maxrighesheet1}
        else {
            if(sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf() &&                                //0 E' SCADUTO?
              j===maxrighesheet1)                                                                               //1 SEI ALLA FINE?
              {sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange((maxrighesheet1+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet1+1)))
              maxrighesheet1 = maxrighesheet1 + 1
              j=maxrighesheet1
              Logger.log("8. Nuovo task non presente nello storico ma non scaduto ->  Inserisco Storico i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}
            else if(sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf()<new Date().valueOf() &&                            //1 E' SCADUTO?
              j===maxrighesheet1)                                                                               //1 SEI ALLA FINE?
              {sheet0.getRange(i+':'+i).copyTo(sheet1.getRange((maxrighesheet1+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet1+1)))
              maxrighesheet1 = maxrighesheet1 + 1
              sheet1.getRange((j+1)+':'+(j+1)).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
              sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[EXP] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
              sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
              maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
              sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).setValue(today)
              sheet0.getRange('D'+ (i)).setValue(tomorrow)
              calEvents[i-2].setAllDayDate(new Date(sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).getValue()))
              sheet1.getRange('D'+ (j+1)).setValue(tomorrow)
              maxrighesheet1 = maxrighesheet1 +1
              j=maxrighesheet1
              Logger.log("9. Nuovo task non presente nello storico ma scaduto -> Insierisco Storico, Log, Aggiorno data e Push nel Calendario i:" + i + " j:" + j +" " + sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue())}
          }
          // K1, K3, K5 testati
          // K2, K4, K6, 7, 8, 9 devono esser testati con lo storico popolato
        }
      }
      if (j===maxrighesheet1){
        scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", 2);
      }
    }
  }
  
  Logger.log("Finale: i/maxrighesheet0: " + i + "/" + maxrighesheet0)
  Logger.log("Finale: j/maxrighesheet1: " + j + "/" + maxrighesheet1)

  if(i===(maxrighesheet0+1) && j===(maxrighesheet1+1)){
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", 2)
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", 2);
  Logger.log("Confronta: END")

  var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("pulisci")
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(currTime + (1000 * 5))) //5 secondi
    .create();
  }
}

function pulisci(){

var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
CancellaTrigger()
Logger.log("Pulisci: START")

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var startI= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_I');
var startJ= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_J');

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar')
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Storico')
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('LOG')

var maxrighesheet0 = sheet0.getLastRow();
var maxrighesheet1 = sheet1.getLastRow();
var maxrighesheet2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();

Logger.log("Pulisco storico da duplicati/obsoleti")
for (var j = Math.max(startJ,2); j <= maxrighesheet1; j++) {
  var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  if(currTime - startTime >=  1000 * 60 * 5) { //5 minuti
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", j);
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", Math.max(startI,2));
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("pulisci")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime + (1000 * 5))) //5 secondi
               .create();
    Logger.log("Pulisci: Sono uscito loop J a i: " + i +"/"+maxrighesheet0 +" e j: " +j + "/"+maxrighesheet1)
    break;
    }
    else {
      for (var i = Math.max(startI,2); i <= maxrighesheet0; i++) {
        var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        
        Logger.log("j/maxrighesheet1: " + j + "/" + maxrighesheet1)
        Logger.log("i/maxrighesheet0: " + i + "/" + maxrighesheet0)
        
        if(currTime - startTime >=  1000 * 60 * 5) { //5 minuti
          scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", j);
          j=j-1
          Logger.log("Pulisci: Sono uscito loop I a i: " + i +"/"+maxrighesheet0 +" e j: " +j + "/"+maxrighesheet1)
          break;
          }  
        else {
          if(
          sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue() === sheet0.getRange('A' +i).getValue() &&                              //1 MATCHA?
          sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf()===sheet0.getRange('D' +i).getValue().valueOf() &&                                            //1 RICORRENTE E DATA CREATA LA STESSA?
          sheet1.getRange('H' +j).getValue().valueOf() === sheet0.getRange('H' +i).getValue().valueOf() &&              //1 LAST UPDATE E' LO STESSO?
          sheet1.getRange('D' +j).getValue().valueOf()>=new Date().valueOf())   
          {i=(maxrighesheet0+1)}
          else if (
            i===maxrighesheet0)
            {sheet1.getRange(j+':'+j).copyTo(sheet2.getRange((maxrighesheet2+1)+':'+(maxrighesheet2+1)))
            sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue('[OBS|CANC] '+ sheet2.getRange('B'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).getValue())
            sheet2.getRange('O'+ (maxrighesheet2+1)).setValue((Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))) 
            maxrighesheet2 = maxrighesheet2+1
            sheet1.deleteRow(j)
            j = Math.max(2,j-1)
            maxrighesheet1=maxrighesheet1 - 1
            Logger.log ("Non mattchato Log j:" + j + " i:" + i +" " + sheet1.getRange('A' +j).getValue())          
          }
        }
      }

      if(i===(maxrighesheet0)){
        scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", 2);
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log("Finale: j/maxrighesheet1: " + j + "/" + maxrighesheet1)
  Logger.log("Finale i/maxrighesheet0: " + i + "/" + maxrighesheet0)
  

  if(i===(maxrighesheet0+2) && j===(maxrighesheet1+1)){
  
  //DOPO TEST lo farò ordinare
  //sheet0.getRange('2:'+maxrighesheet0).sort([{column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  //sheet1.getRange('2:'+maxrighesheet1).sort([{column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  //sheet2.getRange('2:'+maxrighesheet2).sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 15, ascending: true}]);
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_I", 2)
  scriptProperties.setProperty("start_J", 2)
  Logger.log("Confronta: END")}
}
```

See above. I'm not sure what to do

Comment: `confronta` needs to be optimised. #1) every "TEST" has multiple `getRange`, `getValue` and `setValue` (and Logger) . An alternative is, say, `getdataRange().getValues()` so that data is called once. #2) There are 9 "TESTS" (many with similar rules) and resolutions. An alternative might be to run the "TESTS", set a flag for the result, then reprocess the list based on prioritised flags and process only the resolution. #3) `indexOf` might reduce the number of loops. It might also be used with `CONCATENATE` (or similar) to find matches on several fields in one pass.

Comment: If you would like further, specific assistance, then would you please provide sample data for both sheets "0" and "1"; and demonstrate each "TEST using the sample data.

Comment: @Tedinoz the BEAST. I will try to optimize.
I ask also that now i'm experimenting a lot (100%) of `[Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id]`. For sure more long is the script more often this error happen.

Comment: `Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id` That's odd. `Confronta`: line 28-`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` - you're _not_ accessing by ID. Is the data on sheet0 and sheet1 being imported from another sheet/spreadsheet?

Comment: Ideas: #1 - Consider Task#1: looking for a match on A (ID or Title??), N (isRecurrent) and D (End Time). However if A isn't found, then N and D don't matter. #2 - Tasks #1-#5 all test for match on Column A. But the test only needs to be done **once** and the result passed to subsequent tasks. #3 - A partial [example of some optimised script for Task#1](https://justpaste.it/cc53a). This also uses `indexOf` to test for a match on Column A.

Comment: They are all on same spreadsheet on different Sheets.
I will try to use something like `SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID")`

Comment: Well, I think that IS the problem. It’s getting hung up on opening “something” by ID. I was trying to say that ‘getActiveSpreadsheet’ was a **good** thing.

Comment: I'm trying to readapt code with IndexOF Method. And it is way faster (also it removes J loop cycle).
But i'm struggling how to make indexOf of 2 columns. Because for me an event is unique IF it has and ID AND getEndTime different.
I have recurrent events... So many ID equal but with differente EndTime.

Comment: Try: https://justpaste.it/587w6

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz and thanks again. I saw your code and the problem is that  
`var matchResult = histId.indexOf(id); // returns array index, or -1 if not found
    if (matchResult == -1)`

For me if (ID is not found) OR (if ID is found but END date is not found) it should be matchresult ==-1

Not sure if i've explained. In case i will provide an exemple of spreadsheet

Comment: The logic should be: https://justpaste.it/86w7p.

The problem is last taht can't see only the date of matched row (matchresult) but should look into all rows of Historic. OR i can concatenate ID and ad getenddate...

Comment: @Tedinoz I'm working on. Let me do stuffs and i think i will complete. Uisin IndexOF + a ID+getEndTime combination i think i solve performance issues and i will make code more linear as you showed me. I only need few more time and test :S